# Reading empty list of ids from properties file and initialise as empty collection

Tags: java, spring, arraylist, collections

I have the following property in properties file:

```
target.specifiedIds=
```

My model has constructor something like this:

```
   public ConnectionInfo(String type, Set<String> ids) {
        this.type= type;
        this.ids= ids;
    }
```

My spring file initialises constructor as follows:

```
<bean id="something" class="something.ConnectionInfo">
        <constructor-arg value="${report.type}"/>
        <constructor-arg value="#{'${target.specifiedIds}'.split(',')}"/>
```

In the property file, I can get Ids defined or ids not defined in which case my application will handle all possible ids available

```
target.specifiedIds= 54, 88
target.specifiedIds=
```

In the second case, when there is no id's defined, the above would add an element with empty string to the  `Set` collection even though nothing has been specified. How can I prevent this `SPEL`? Or is there a better alternative?

```
if (!connection.getIds().isEmpty()) {
        Set<String> acceptedIds = connection.getIds();
        //do something
    }
```

The above should return empty when no ids specified? How can I handle this?